# How can I click a link which is in button with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Can anyone help me please, how can I click a button, which is inside a div? While, on first page, the button to 2nd page is availalable to click, but with my code I cannot achieve it.

Here is my code:

```
> WebElement btn_Submit =
> driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class*='bodylink']"));
>             
>             clickable=isClickable(btn_Submit);
>             if(clickable){
>                 btn_Submit.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
> 
>             }
```

Here is excerpt from page:

```
<div id="pagingBody">
<div style="margin-bottom:10px;font-weight:bold;" id="ex-gen3932">100 Total Results</div>
[1 - 50] |
<a id="ex-gen3926" class="bodylink" href="#" onclick="gosearch('PowRan',51); return false;">[51 - 100]</a>
</div>
```

Comment: In ur code we are not seeing any href link like 'bodylink'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
WebElement btn_Submit = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='bodylink']"));
```

Try with:

```
WebElement btn_Submit = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='pagingBody']//following::a[1]));
```

> If required induce `ExplicitWait` i.e. `WebDriverWait` for the button to be clickable and then call `click()` method.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: It didn't work. I cannot put id, because it is being generated randomly, so I tested ur code with class, but Exception occured: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"a[@class='bodylink']"}

Comment: Ok, can you consider to format the HTML DOM as per the actual one. We can create the `xpath` wrt `div id="pagingBody"` and call the `click()` method. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't see the button. I guess, the solution is sth to do with onclick method of a link.

Comment: Can you confirm if the format of the actual HTML DOM is just like the one in your Question? Or it is a bit different?

Comment: It should be the same. Everything is stated in question

Comment: Check my updated Answer and let me know the status. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have debugged this and the element is not null.

instead of doing:

```
btn_Submit.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

try doing:

```
btn_Submit.click();
```

This should then raise you `onclick` event.

Comment: It didn't work and I assume the reason is that selenium cannot yet find this button to click

Comment: You assume? debug it and find out.

Comment: I am sure that it cannot find the button yet

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebElement btn_Submit =
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div > a.bodylink"));
btn_Submit.click();
```